# How to remove an empty space below a UIToolbar after opening an Action Sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uikit

I have a view controller that has a set of toolbar items. When I push that view controller to the screen the layout looks correct, as shown below:

[image: Correct Layout]

After opening an action sheet controller, the layout begins to show issues, like so (notice the small gap between the UIToolbar and the bottom of the screen):

[image: Small gap]

After I close the action sheet, the layout issue is exacerbated.

[image: Big layout issue]

There isn't any part of the code the code that modifies `edgesForExtendedLayout` after or during presenting the action sheet so I'm not entirely sure why this is happening.

To give some clarity I'm using `setToolbarItems` and `setToolbarHidden` to display the toolbar. The view hierarchy is as follows:

UITabBarController (hidden UITabBar)
-> UINavigationController
   -> UIViewController (that displays the UIToolbar)

Comment: Hello, I don't understand the point of using a tabBarController and put a toolbar on top of it ? Are you using the tab bar items AND the tool bar items ?

Comment: I'm not using the tab bar items at all, it's only a toolbar on this specific view controller. There's a segmented control in the navigation header that switches between the view controllers.